# CKEditor - Trigger dialog ok button

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor and I wrote a plugin that pops up a the CKEditor dialog.

I need to re design the ok button and add to the footer more elements like textbox and checkbox but it's seems to be to complicated to do so, so I've hide the footer part and created a uiElement in the dialog content with all what I need but now what I want is to trigger the okButton in the hidden footer but I can't find a way to do it..

Anyone?!

Answer (score 5):

There may be a better way, but here's how I'm doing it:

```
var ckDialog = window.CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent(),
    ckCancel = ckDialog._.buttons['cancel'],
    ckOk = ckDialog._.buttons['ok'];

ckOK.click();
```

The trick is to get the button and then use the CKEditor Button API to simulate the click. For some reason, I was unable to call dialog.getButton('ok') because getButton is undefined for some reason. My method digs into the private data, which I doubt is the best way to do it.

From the onShow event (when defining the dialog), I was able to get the ok button like the docs indicate:

```
onShow: function () {
    var okBtn = this.getButton('ok');
    ...
}
```

Here's the Button API: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.button, and you can access the dialog API there too (I'm assuming you've already been there!!!)

Comment: Thanks! Actually I've ended up adding elements with jquery to the footer and classes to the ok button element.. maybe not the best way but it was the fastest.

Comment: If you want the most flexibility inside a ckeditor dialog, check out the iframedialog plugin. I just built a media uploader with it, which can't imagine trying to do using the ckeditor API.

Answer (score 3):

You might try to add this line in your plugin.js.

```
var dialog = this.getDialog();
document.getElementById(dialog.getButton('ok').domId).click();
```

In my custom plugin, i just hide the "ok" button instead of the whole footer.
Below is a part of my plugin.js statements.

```
{
    type : 'fileButton',
    id : 'uploadButton',
    label : 'Upload file',
    'for' : [ 'tab1', 'upload' ],
    filebrowser :
    {
        action : 'QuickUpload',
        onSelect : function(fileUrl, data){
            var dialog = this.getDialog();
            dialog.getContentElement('tab1','urlTxt').setValue(fileUrl);
            document.getElementById(dialog.getButton('ok').domId).click();
        }
    }
}
```

btw, i'm using **CKEditor 4.0 (revision 769d96134b)**

Comment: Thanks! Actually I've ended up adding elements with jquery to the footer and classes to the ok button element.. maybe not the best way but it was the fastest.